# "Untitled" can't be opened because the original item can't be found

Tags: macos, finder, disk-utility, permission, external-disk

Currently, my external SSD can be mounted and showed in finder sidebar. But, I can't open my disk and "Get Info" option is missing, then this error came.

[image]

Here's my disk info.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried:

- Relaunch Finder
- Reboot
- Remount disk
- Go to Folder -> `/Volumes/Untitled` (Show empty folder)
- First Aid (Operation not permitted)

[image]

But none of these solution works. Can you help me fix this issue without reformat my drive? Thanks!

Update:
I tried ls command but it throws `ls: Untitled: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Is there anything else in the Volumes folder when the drive is mounted? Does the Untitled folder go away when you unmount the drive in Disk Utility? Can you mount the drive on another Mac or an iPad, if you have one? Most importantly, do you have backups of the data on the drive?

Comment: 1. Yes, there's Data, Macintosh HD, and Untitled.
2. Yes.
3. Unfortunately, I don't have another Mac or an iPad.
4. Nope :(

Answer (score 1):

After looking for answers, I have managed to unlock my external drive by fixing the permission issue in recovery mode (thanks to [Aaron M](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/466442/509814)).

What I done:

- Disk Utility -> Select `Untitled` Volume -> First Aid
- Open Terminal -> `diskutil disableOwnership /Volume/Untitled`

Finally, I am able to access my external drive. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Yikes! It's scary to possibly lose data. I've been in this situation and may be able to help.

In this case, the reported error message is a permissions issue.
I know of two things you can try in order to override permissions on this volume.

**Option 1: Disable Permissions:**

Use "Get Info" on the troubled drive (in this case "Untitled") to enable  "Ignore ownership on this volume".
This is a temporary change and is reversible. Requires unlocking first.
More Detailed instructions from Apple are [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp1204/mac).

Example screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot of MacOS Finder Get-Info Ignore Ownership Setting]

**Option 2: Write Over the Permissions:**

*Caution: Proceed with care. If you don't know what you're doing, don't try this on a bootable volume.*

You can change the permissions to "Read & Write for everyone" and apply those settings to all enclosed items using Get-Info or with the CHMOD command via the terminal.
More detailed Instructions are clearly written up on HowToGeek [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/669095/how-to-set-file-permissions-on-mac/).

Comment: This is weird. When I opened 'Get Info,' it said 'You have unknown access.' And if I try to look for my 'Untitled' Drive permission, it throws 'Operation not permitted.'